# Change the color or texture of a SCNText node object (Swift - Scenekit)

Tags: colors, swift, textures, ios8, scenekit

How do I set the texture of a SCNText object? This is what I have and nothing changes in the appearance:

```
// myNode is a working SCNText element 

let mat = SCNMaterial()
met.diffuse.contents = UIImage(contentsOfFile: "texture.png")
myNode.geometry.firstMaterial = mat
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> A text geometry may contain one, three, or five geometry elements:
>
> If its extrusionDepth property is 0.0, the text geometry has one element corresponding to its one visible side.
> If its extrusion depth is greater than zero and its chamferRadius property is 0.0, the text geometry has three elements, corresponding to its front, back, and extruded sides.
> If both extrusion depth and chamfer radius are greater than zero, the text geometry has five elements, corresponding to its front, back, extruded sides, front chamfer, and back chamfer.
> Scene Kit can render each element using a different material. For details, see the description of the materials property in SCNGeometry Class Reference.

just like for any other geometry, simply set its `materials` property.